# Ошибки к консоли (js)

Tags: javascript, html, анимация

[image: ошибки в консоли]

Собсна все на скрине.
Код:

```
$('.news-block_main').hover(
function(){$('.news-block-hover_main').show('fast')('display','block');},
function(){$('.news-block-hover_main').hide('fast')('display','none');}
);
```

сам код работает, смущают только ошибки в консоль.

Comment: насколько я вижу зачем-то написаны лишние скобки после вызовов функций show/hide, убери их и ошибок не будет, я про `('display','block')`

Comment: Нет, `'display','block'` тоже надо убрать.

Comment: Если убрать скобки - код перестает функционировать

Comment: @nofate - спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функции [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) и [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) возвращают ***объект*** jQuery, поэтому результат вызова этих функций не может быть использовать как функция.

Достаточно просто убрать непонятные строки

```
('display','block')
('display','none')
```

и все заработает

```
$('.news-block_main').hover(
    function(){$('.news-block-hover_main').show('fast');},
    function(){$('.news-block-hover_main').hide('fast');}
);
```